# File directory doesn't parse correctly in Seg2Cat

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat, ee4

I'm seeing an issue in Low Seg2Cat where the {last_segment_category_image} variable seems to not be parsing the file directory & is returning the following: {filedir_10}gaf-logo.png.
I am using {last_segment_category_description} just after it & it is displaying correctly.
Am I using the Category image tag incorrectly. or might there be something else going on here?  I'm on EE4.1.2

Thanks.
Russ

Comment: Strange it seems the Mysql table content is copied indeed tge category_image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File paths are only parsed in the Category Image field, not in the Category Description field, and only if the Parse File Paths setting is set to Yes.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't catch the "Parse File Paths Setting"

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use this little utility-addon to parse the {filedir_x} into the full path.

I have [added an updated version of parse_file_paths](https://github.com/terrybritton/parse_file_paths) by rsanchez as a fork which now will work in EE 3.x and up.

All I did was to add the addon.setup.php file to the zip file with the appropriate fields filled in. The original code still works like a champ!

This works very well with the Query module. It takes the raw results containing {filedir_X} and expands that into the actual file path, using a routine already in the typography.php library in EE but for some reason that is not used by the query module by default. This little addon makes up for that.